# Check if position is inside HTML tag

Tags: node.js

I want to find if a particular position is within a tag of html.  (node.js)

Example:

```
This text is <a href="http://ex.com"> inside a tag </a> not inside <b>not inside</b> not inside of the <b /> tag.
```

Given the position p, how can I test if I am currently in a HTML tag or not? I suppose I'll have to test if I am in one of these situations
p = position:

Test one of these:

- < p > ... </>
- <...> p </>
- < p />

Appreciate the help!

Comment: I am having trouble understanding what the problem is. Please check out this helpful guide from SO https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I added an explanation.

Comment: What do you mean by a "position". Are you doing string analysis? Is a position a character index in the HTML string?

Comment: yes! position is the index. a number at the string.

Comment: are you trying to test for all html tags?

Comment: yes, for all tags